# Как удалить из HTML файла лишние блоки?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, файлы

У меня есть 1000 HTML страниц.

Как я могу удалить из HTML файла лишние блоки и оставить только тот, который изображен на скриншоте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужен конкретно один блок и его содержимое из 1000 html файлов ?

Comment: "удалить лишние блоки" и "оставить только изображенный на скриншоте" - не одно и то же? ;) дайте пример файла и что хотите оставить в нем?

Comment: @WilteRatenau нет. Мне нужно через цикл удалить во всех страницах (они разные) удалить все, кроме одного блока. С циклом все понятное, а вот как удалить лишние блоки... У меня идей нет.

Comment: @Jack_oS, вот пример [страницы](https://gist.github.com/j0sephAnime/71898c28f7c8954289f1d28fcf58fe88).

Comment: вы не сказали, что в нем нужно удалить, а что - оставить...

Comment: @VladimirPutin _вот пример страницы_, вся информация должна быть в вопросе в текстовом виде, не в комментарии, и тем более, не по ссылке. [Поправте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1285698/edit), пожалуйста.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример для одного `.html` файла:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                              # импорт BeautifulSoup


with open('index.html', 'r') as f:
    html = f.read()                                        # чтение файла в html

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')                  # объект Beautiful Soup
required_div = soup.find('div', class_='l-entry__content') # поиск искомого div-а по классу

with open('out.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(required_div.prettify())                       # запись найденного в out.html
```

В `out.html` - только `<div class="l-entry__content"> ... </div>`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скормите парсеру в цикле ваши тысячи `.html` файлов (меняя название выходного файла, например), - получите еще столько же...

Возможно, проще брать только нужное (текст статьи, автора, дату), и после обработки сохранять в csv все результаты сразу...